# Заполнение listview из связанных таблиц из БД sqlite

Tags: activity, android, listview, java, sqlite

Привет! Существует 2 активности, обе унаследованы от ListActivity и обе заполняются информацией из БД sqlite. Первая активность: listview заполняется группами, тут всё норм. Вторая активность: listview заполняется подгруппами в зависимости от выбранной группы, вот тут и проблема - listview не заполняется. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку!

Код первой активности:

```
public class GroupActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String DB_NAME = "SpravDB.sqlite";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Groups";
private static final String GROUP_ID = "_id";  // ключи групп.
private static final String GROUP_NAME = "Name_Group";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> groups;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

    SpravSQLhelper dbOpenHelper = new SpravSQLhelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

    fillGroups();
    setUpList();
}

private void setUpList() {

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, groups));
    OnItemClickListener itemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intentF = new Intent();
            intentF.setClass(GroupActivity.this, SubGroupActivity.class);
            String itemid = new Integer(position).toString();
            Bundle a = new Bundle();
            a.putString("itemid", itemid);
            intentF.putExtras(a);
            startActivity(intentF);
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);
}

private void fillGroups() {
    groups = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor groupCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME }, null, null, null, null, GROUP_NAME);
    groupCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!groupCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            String name = groupCursor.getString(1);
            groups.add(name);
        } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    groupCursor.close();
}
}
```

Код второй активности:

```
public class SubGroupActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String DB_NAME = "SpravDB.sqlite";
private static final String GROUP_ID = "ID_Group"; // ключи групп, в зависимости //от которых будет заполняться подгруппа
private static final String SUBGROUP_ID = "_id"; // ключи подгрупп
private static final String SUBGROUP_NAME = "Name_Subgroup";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList subgroups;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subgroup);
    SpravSQLhelper dbOpenHelper = new SpravSQLhelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    fillSubGroups();
    setUpList();

}

private void setUpList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subgroups));
    OnItemClickListener itemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Вы выбрали " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);

}

private void fillSubGroups() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intentF = getIntent();
    String ID_Group = intentF.getStringExtra("itemid");
    subgroups = new ArrayList<String>();
    String TABLE_NAME = "Subgroups";
    Cursor subgroupCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            SUBGROUP_ID, GROUP_ID, SUBGROUP_NAME }, GROUP_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(ID_Group) }, null, null, null,
            null);
    subgroupCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!subgroupCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            String name = subgroupCursor.getString(1);
            subgroups.add(name);
        } while (subgroupCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    subgroupCursor.close();

}

}
```